# I want to get distinct tuples in Postgres where (a,b,c) and (a,c,b) are same so it should show only one of them

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table  films

```
   select title,length from film where length = 117;

         title          | length
------------------------+--------
 Chamber Italian        |    117
 Affair Prejudice       |    117
 Graffiti Love          |    117
 Magic Mallrats         |    117
 Resurrection Silverado |    117
```

I want  to do self join the table twice

```
SELECT
distinct(
    f1.title,
    f2.title,
    f3.title),
    f1.length
FROM
    film f1
INNER JOIN film f2
    ON f1.film_id <> f2.film_id  AND
       f1.length = f2.length
INNER JOIN film f3
    ON f1.film_id <> f3.film_id AND f2.film_id <> f3.film_id AND
       f2.length = f3.length

WHERE f1.title = 'Chamber Italian';

                               row                               | length
-----------------------------------------------------------------+--------
 ("Chamber Italian","Affair Prejudice","Graffiti Love")          |    117
 ("Chamber Italian","Affair Prejudice","Magic Mallrats")         |    117
 ("Chamber Italian","Affair Prejudice","Resurrection Silverado") |    117
 ("Chamber Italian","Graffiti Love","Affair Prejudice")          |    117
 ("Chamber Italian","Graffiti Love","Magic Mallrats")            |    117
 ("Chamber Italian","Graffiti Love","Resurrection Silverado")    |    117
 ("Chamber Italian","Magic Mallrats","Affair Prejudice")         |    117
 ("Chamber Italian","Magic Mallrats","Graffiti Love")            |    117
 ("Chamber Italian","Magic Mallrats","Resurrection Silverado")   |    117
 ("Chamber Italian","Resurrection Silverado","Affair Prejudice") |    117
 ("Chamber Italian","Resurrection Silverado","Graffiti Love")    |    117
 ("Chamber Italian","Resurrection Silverado","Magic Mallrats")   |    117
```

but as You can see

```
("Chamber Italian","Affair Prejudice","Graffiti Love")
("Chamber Italian","Graffiti Love","Affair Prejudice")
```

are same just arrangement is diff how to eliminate this

Just asking as I am learning sql.

so basically the output I want is

```
                           *
                               row                               | length
-----------------------------------------------------------------+--------
 ("Chamber Italian","Affair Prejudice","Graffiti Love")          |    117
 ("Chamber Italian","Affair Prejudice","Magic Mallrats")         |    117
 ("Chamber Italian","Affair Prejudice","Resurrection Silverado") |    117
 ("Chamber Italian","Graffiti Love","Magic Mallrats")            |    117
 ("Chamber Italian","Graffiti Love","Resurrection Silverado")    |    117
 ("Chamber Italian","Magic Mallrats","Resurrection Silverado")   |    117
```

I want (a,b,c) (a,c,b) to be considered as same and choose any one of them

Comment: So what exactly is the output you are looking for? You have five different films, but apparently you only want to get three of them. Which three?

Comment: so in above out put you can see 16 rows  - in which                                             
("Chamber Italian","Affair Prejudice","Graffiti Love") -> can be seen as (a,b,c)
("Chamber Italian","Graffiti Love","Affair Prejudice")-> can be seen as (a,c,b)

so I just want to keep any one of them as there meaning is same 

there are many pairs in above 16 rows which do the same I just want to eliminate them

Answer (score 0):

put in an arbitrary tie breaker

```
    ON 1.film_id < f2.film AND ...
```

instead of your symmetric `not` <> operator
why?

because everything greater (or lesser)

is also not equal
but the other way around will be skipped.

also simplify second join

```
...
FROM
    film f1
INNER JOIN film f2
    ON f1.film_id < f2.film_id  AND
       f1.length = f2.length
INNER JOIN film f3
    ON f2.film_id < f3.film_id AND
       f2.length = f3.length
```

since '<' is transitive it implicitly covers the
`f1.film_id < f3.film_id` 
case.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
SELECT 
  distinct f1.title as title1, 
  (select title from film where title <> f1.title order by title limit 1) as title2, 
  (select title from film where title <> f1.title order by title desc limit 1) as title3,
  f1.length
from film f1 
where f1.title = 'Chamber Italian'
limit 1;
```